# Displaying xml+xslt in WebBrowser control

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-phone-7

I need to display an xml using xslt transformation in WebBrowser control in Windows Phone 7.1.
I saved xml and xsl files into isolated file storage. Then I did

```
uxWebBrowser.Source = new Uri(xmlFileName, UriKind.Relative);
```

Xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mytransf.xsl"?>
<root>
  <ta>foo<ta>
</root>
```

But I see only "foo" without any transformations. Basically, it doesn't matter what I set in href attribute above. The result is always the same. Seems WebBrowser cannot find mytransf.xsl. I'm sure that this file exists in the right place. The interesting thing is that in Windows Phone 7.0 everything was fine.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: The same question http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/92790.aspx

Comment: It seems a bug in the Mango update https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/698106/internet-explorer-and-webbrowser-control-in-windows-phone-mango-render-xml-xslt-incorrectly#details