# XSL in windows phone

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

I need to make XSL transformation of my xml-file on windows phone 7 platform. The problem is that Microsoft excluded System.Xml.Xsl namespace from WP7 SDK. So there is no XslTransform class. 
Could anyone propose any workaround of this?

UPDATE:
I have articles in xml format that I need to represent to the user in human readable form. Using of web-service which does this work for me is impossible because application should be completely Internet-agnostic. WebBrowser control used to work well but last Mango update [broke this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908604/displaying-xmlxslt-in-webbrowser-control).

Comment: By 'human readable form', are you thinking HTML here? If so, is the XML in essentially the same structure as the target HTML, so you're mostly looking to rewrite XML elements and attributes as HTML elements and attributes? Or do you dramatically restructure the XML in order to form HTML?

Comment: Yes, I mean HTML here. Nope, I don't want to restructure the XML dramatically. It's good idea to use just my own string.replace approach. I will use it as last resort. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Microsoft excluded the XslTransform class from WP7, you will need another implementation.

Since the XslTransform has always been available for other platforms in .NET, it might not be easy to find an open source implementation in C# which you could use. Perhaps you could look into adapting a Xsl processor from another framework such as Java. Unfortunately, that might be a considerable amount of work.

If you can't find anything that can be readily used for WP7, perhaps you should ask yourself, if you really need it ? Can you change your architecture to work around this ?

As a last resort, you could build a web service that does the Xsl Transformation for you. The obvious downside to this is that the phone has to be connected to the internet to use it - and the service has to be up. In other words, it's adding a lot of complexity to the solution (unless you are already pulling the data from the server, in which case I would simply do the transform on the server side before returning the data).

Answer (score 1):

@Pashec, in order to suggest alternatives, it would help if you could explain the nature of the transformation you're looking to implement. After all, XSLT is such a general purpose transformation language, you could be doing just about anything with it. Two common transformation scenarios are: (1) copy an input XML document mostly intact, except for adding/modifying/deleting a few selected elements or attributes; and (2) transform the fundamental structure of the input XML document such as grouping elements, mapping between two disparate hierarchies, etc. Can you give us an idea of the range of transformations you're trying to accomplish?

In addition to understanding what you're goal is so we can suggest programming approaches to get ther, there are two avenues that seem worth a little investigation. First, in your scenario would it make sense to send the XML to a hosted service to transform? If you're already using services for other purposes, that might be reasonable; if not, then that might be a bit much.

Second, in the .NET Framework, XSLT compiles to an in-memory assembly. The xsltc.exe utility can be used to compile XSLT transformations to a regular (i.e., file-based) .NET assembly. [Read about xsltc here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/antosha/archive/2007/05/28/xsltc-compile-xslt-to-.net-assembly.aspx) and elsewhere. I haven't tried adapting an xsltc-generated assembly to be usable in a Windows Phone application, but that could be viable technique.

Comment: In some cases you are able to include silverlight libraries in your windowa phone project. Try this. Add the reference (library) from the silverlight framework and see if it works. There are situations where this is used such as the rss feed reader. Msdn even has an example where it loads the silcerlight library into the wp7 project to handle the feed.

Comment: @invalidusername, interesting idea. It's worth to try.

Answer (score 0):

@Pashec replied in the question's comments that the transformation he wants to create doesn't significantly restructure the document, then another viable solution would be to use and XmlReader and XmlWiter pair, reading elements and attributes from the reader and writing the corresponding desired elements and attributes with the writer.

The first example in [How to: Parse XML with XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) illustrates this approach exactly.

This approach has a distinct advantage over XSLT, as this does not create XML DOMs for either source or target document. An XML DOM is typically on the order of 10x the size of the serialized (angle-bracket form) of the XML.